# does sfWidgetFormSelect provide a string or an int of the selected item?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony-1.4

I'm having an annoying problem. I'm trying to find out what fields of a form were changed, and then insert that into a table. I managed to var_dump in doUpdateObjectas shown in the following

```
public function doUpdateObject($values) 
{ 
    parent::doUpdateObject($values);
    var_dump($this->getObject()->getModified(false));
    var_dump($this->getObject()->getModified(true));
 }
```

And it seems like $this->getObject()->getModified seems to work in giving me both before and after values by setting it to either true or false.

The problem that I'm facing right now is that, some how, sfWidgetFormSelect seems to be saving one of my fields as a string. before saving, that exact same field was an int. (I got this idea by var_dump both before and after).

Here is what the results on both var dumps showed:

```
array(1) {["annoying_field"]=> int(3)} array(1) {["annoying_field"]=>string(1)"3"}
```

This seems to cause doctrine to think that this is a modification and thus gives a false positive.

In my base form, I have

```
under $this->getWidgets()
'annoying_field'    => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),

under $this->setValidators
'annoying_field'    => new sfValidatorInteger(array('required' => false)),
```

and lastly in my configured Form.class.php I have reconfigured the file as such:

```
$this->widgetSchema['annoying_field'] = new sfWidgetFormSelect(array('choices' => $statuses));
```

statuses is an array containing values like {""a", "b", "c", "d"}

and I just want the index of the status to be stored in the database.

And also how can I insert the changes into another database table? let's say my Log table?

Any ideas and advice as to why this is happen is appreciated, I've been trying to figure it out and browsing google for various keywords with no avail.

Thanks!

Edit:

ok so I created another field, integer in my schema just for testing. 
I created an entry, saved it, and edited it.

this time the same thing happened!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
It turns out I forgot to do a custom validator to use the array key instead.

Answer (score 1):

first if you what the status_id to be saved in the database, you should define your status array like this:

```
 {1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c", 4 => "d"}
```

So that way he know that 1 should be rendered like "a" and so on. Then, when saving, only the index should be saved.

About saving in another database, my advise is to modify the doSave method defined by the Form class yo match your needs. I only know how Propel deals with it, maybe this could help:

the doSave method dose something like this:

```
  protected function doSave($con = null)
  {
    if (null === $con)
    {
      $con = $this->getConnection();
    }

    $old = $this->getObject()->getModifiedValues($this);//Define this
    $new_object = new Log($old);//Create a new log entry
    $new_object->save($con));//save it!

    $this->updateObject();

    $this->getObject()->save($con);

    // embedded forms
    $this->saveEmbeddedForms($con);
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Edit:

This is an example extracted from a model in one of my applications and its working ok:

Schema:

```
[...]    
funding_source_id:
  type: integer
  required: true
[...]
```

Form:

```
$this->setWidget('funding_source_id', new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
   'choices' => array(1 => 'asdads', 2 => '123123123' , 3 => 'asd23qsdf'),
)));


$this->setValidator('funding_source_id', new sfValidatorChoice(array(
   'choices' => array(1 => 'asdads', 2 => '123123123' , 3 => 'asd23qsdf'),
  'required' => true
)));
```

About the log thing, that could be quite more complex, you should read the current implementation of the doSave method in the base form class, currently sfFomrObject on Symfony1.4., and when and how it delegates object dealing with modified values.

Comment: Hey! Adding 1 => "a" etc might just work! Why didn't that occur to me. D'oh! Oh yea, maybe I should do it under doSave instead of doUpdateObject. Thanks a lot for that! I'll try it when I get back home, but for now, it's an up vote nonetheless.

Comment: Hey han hope that works out for you, i'll be expeting your results! And i'm more than happy to help!

Comment: hey man, unfortunately it doesn't work :( I tried detecting the changes under doSave, but they turn up blank. i tried the array thing too. it still remains the same :(

Comment: I just modified it, try that one. It's working ok in my application and i've used it a lot. Check your schema, run a build --all-classes to make sure your using the lastest schema modifications, clear cache, and re check your code.

Comment: hey dude. I checked my schema, it was type integer as well. I did my form from  your code as well. However putting the getModified still gives me teh same result when i var_dump :(

Comment: Well i'm running out of ideas, the best advise i could give you is:

check the doSave (you should look at the implenentation in the Base Object class) and doUpdate function (on the Base Object Peer class). Those functions take care of the object saving strategy. Also the form has a getTaintedValues, witch is the values setted in the form after validation. Also check the doCreate and doUpdate actions in the Class module, and make your own decision using the parameters sent to it.